# C#: Sorting with anonymous function

Tags: c#, sorting

Let's say I have a list of objects, and I want to sort it by the items DateModified property. Why can't I use a delegate like this? How should I sort these by DateModified if not as shown below:

```
public string SortByDateModified(List<CartItem> items)
{
    items.Sort(new Func<CartItem, CartItem, bool>((itemA, itemB) =>
    {
        return itemA.DateModified < itemB.DateModified;
    }));
}
```

Comment: I assume you shortened the function for demo purposes? Because it is supposed to return a string but does not return anything.

Comment: Time to select an answer mistah :)

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Why not use a lambda expression?

```
public string SortByDateModified(List<CartItem> items) 
{ 
    items.Sort((a, b) => a.DateModified.CompareTo(b.DateModified)); 
}
```

Comment: Definitely.  Jeff's answer was *correct*, but *yuck*.  A lambda is so much cleaner.

Comment: One small note, you missed a `)` :)

Comment: This is with caveat - you must be targeting .Net 3.5 or greater.  If you are targeting 2.0 for compatibility reasons, the delegate answer must be used.

Comment: Question of preference.  Some developers dislike lambda expressions.

Comment: @Karlth, that would be a valid statement when this was posted 5 years ago. It's pretty silly at this stage to avoid lambda expressions. Might as well program in Fortran or Cobol if you're not going to be open to new things.

Comment: @SamuelNeff I think you would have a very valid point if the capabilities of the standard C# language was very limited, but it isn't.  The problem with using linq/lambda within C# code is that you are using two very different programming constructs at the same time, something that should be avoided in large project.  (All in my opinion of course!)

Comment: There are environments where lambdas or even delegates can cause crashes or buggy behavior. I've seen this in Unity when using lambdas inline delegates and deploying to iOS.

Comment: @jjxtra that is not a valid reason to say not to use lambdas in C#. That's a bug in Unity which represents a tiny minority of the .NET applications run.

Comment: @SamuelNeff Thanks Samuel, I love seeing all the opinions and view points :)

Comment: @jjxtra agreed :)

Answer (score 17):

If you don't want to use lambdas or greater than .NET 2.0, use this:

```
public string SortByDateModified(List<CartItem> items) 
{ 
    items.Sort(delegate(CartItem itemA, CartItem itemB) 
    { 
        return itemA.DateModified.CompareTo(itemB.DateModified); 
    }); 
}
```

In my experience, in environments such as Unity, lambdas and even delegates can cause crashes or problems, especially on platforms like iOS. In that case you would want to make your sorter a separate function like so:

```
int SortCartItemFunction(CartItem itemA, CartItem itemB) 
{ 
    return itemA.DateModified.CompareTo(itemB.DateModified); 
}
```

Then you could pass it to your sort call like this:

```
items.Sort(SortCartItemFunction);
```

Comment: 1+ but voting limit reached :(

Comment: Thank you. Lambdas make my codes very unreadable, and hard to evolve :[ I need to sort objects of unknown type, and used delegate in .net app by your prompting. <code>list_array.Sort(delegate (CObj x, CObj y) {                                                     return Comparer.DefaultInvariant.Compare(
                            typeof(CObj).GetProperty(str_name).GetValue(y, null),
                            typeof(CObj).GetProperty(str_name).GetValue(x, null)                            ); }); </code>

Answer (score 11):

The [`Sort`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w56d4y5z.aspx) method takes a delegate called [`Comparison<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tfakywbh.aspx). You're trying to pass in a `Func<int, int, bool>`, which is itself a delegate. There is no conversion between the delegate `Func<int, int, bool>` and the delegate `Comparison<T>`.

You can, however, use a [lambda expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx).

```
items.Sort((a, b) => a.DateModified.CompareTo(b.DateModified));
```

Indeed, you use this very lambda expression and pass it into the `Func<int, int, bool>` constructor*. However, there is no need. A lambda expression can be converted into any delegate whos signature matches - that is `(a, b) => a.DateModified.CompareTo(b.DateModified)` can be assigned to something typed `Func<int, int, int>` or something typed `Comparison<T>`. In this case we pass it in to something which expects a `Comparison<T>`.

`*` With one minor adjustment. Sort expectes an integer as a return type. Negative values indicate less than, 0 indicates equal, and positive values indicate greater than.

Answer (score 0):

`bool` is not useful in such a delegate, usually `int` is used because you need 3 values to represent the results of the comparison, less than, equal and greater than. .NET collections usually (if not always) assume -1 means less than, 0 means equal and 1 means greater than.

You would then, in your delegate, have to check if value x is less, equal or greater than value y. An interesting thing to note here is that if you flip the results, for example compare y with x instead you will sort in the opposite direction.

For the easiest way to sort the dates, check [JohnC's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2122012/c-sorting-with-anonymous-function/2122038#2122038), or [Sam's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2122012/c-sorting-with-anonymous-function/2122054#2122054).