# c# What is this delegate within a sort

Tags: c#, filenames, streamreader

I don't understand the logic in the using delegate in this syntax. I'm looking for ways to sort a string and came across this...

```
 Array.Sort (thing, delegate (Things c1, Things c2)
            {
                return c1.Item.CompareTo(c2.Item); 
            });
```

Comment: This is called an anonymous function.

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2122012/c-sorting-with-anonymous-function

Answer (score 3):

For certain classes which belong to the .NET framework, like the **String** class and the classes which represent a number (int, float, decimal, ...), the delegate is **optional** because the interface **IComparable** (see @Idle_Mind answer) is already implemented.

You might define this delegate if you want to **implement a special behaviour** or if you want to use the comparison mechanism on a non-editable class **which doesn't implement IComparable**.

Considering you have to sort a string normally :

```
string s = "eabdfc"; //String to sort
char[] sa = s.ToCharArray(); //Convert to array
Array.Sort(sa); //Sort without any delegate
Console.WriteLine(new string(sa)); // The new string sorted
```

Considering you have to sort a string in the other direction, you can replace the Array.Sort line by :

```
Array.Sort(sa, (x, y) => x.CompareTo(y) * -1);
```

Why ? Because CompareTo must return :

- -1 if element **x < y**
- 0 if element **x = y**
- 1 if element **x > y**

So, if you want to use Array.Sort with any classes you have to : either implement **IComparable** interface (if it's an user defined class), or define the delegate.

To sum up: the delegate offer more flexibility because we can write different behaviours at different places for the same class or the same object while IComparable offer a default behaviour for a class.

I hope my english is understandable, feel free to correct me.

Answer (score 1):

The delegate, known as an anonymous function, allows you to declare a comparison mechanism without needing a completely separate function as below:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Things t1 = new Things();
        t1.Item = "z";
        Things t2 = new Things();
        t2.Item = "a";

        Things[] things = new Things[]{ t1, t2};
        Array.Sort(things, CompareThings);

        foreach(Things t in things)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(t.Item);
        }
    }

    private int CompareThings(Things c1, Things c2)
    {
        return c1.Item.CompareTo(c2.Item);
    }
```

[Here's an example on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w56d4y5z(v=vs.110).aspx) showing two versions of a sort, one with an anonymous function, and one with a declared function (as above).

As a side note, the explicit comparison of `c1.Item` to `c2.Item` is necessary because .Net doesn't know how it should compare one "Things" instance to another.  If you implement the [IComparable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icomparable(v=vs.110).aspx) interface, however, then your code becomes cleaner as you don't need the anonymous or separate function:

```
public class Things : IComparable<Things>
{
    public string Item = "";

    int IComparable<Things>.CompareTo(Things other)
    {
        return this.Item.CompareTo(other.Item);
    }

}
```

Followed by:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Things t1 = new Things();
        t1.Item = "z";
        Things t2 = new Things();
        t2.Item = "a";

        Things[] things = new Things[]{ t1, t2};
        Array.Sort(things); // <-- the intenal implementation of CompareTo() we added to class Things will be used!

        foreach(Things t in things)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(t.Item);
        }
    }
```